# SQL Server : backup database with T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am looking for a way to backup a SQL Server database with T-SQL. I do no have root access to this server through the console, as my only access comes through SQL Server Management Studio.

Could someone please show me the SQL that I could use to export the raw SQL for my entire database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BACKUP DATABASE @strDB TO  DISK =@BackupFile WITH RETAINDAYS = 10, NAME = N'MyDataBase_DATA-Full Database Backup', STATS = 10`

You must define @BackupFile and @strDB as the database name.

All of this is free in Books Online which you can find online.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have access to the server through Management Studio, where do you expect it to stream your backup? Getting the T-SQL to work is one thing - getting SQL Server to be able to write the backup to a place where you can access it is quite another. You may want to look at Red-Gate's SQL Azure Backup:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/